# Importing VISA waveform from an oscilloscope into Python

Tags: python, unicode, visa

I having problems with the return result from this VISA acquisition call:

```
    ribData = []
    ribData = inst.query('CURVe?')
```

I am using this call to grab a waveform from an oscilloscope. I am developing this program in Python.

If the values are positive, the call returns the binary values and I can graph them, but if I drop the waveform on the scope below the halfway point I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:/_Python/TDS3054/mainTds.py", line 107, in cButton
       ribData = inst.query('CURVe?')
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 384, in query
       return self.read()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 309, in read
       message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 401: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I use the following VISA calls to set up the oscilloscope prior to the acquisition.

```
    inst.write('DATa:SOUrce CH2')
    inst.write('DATa:WIDth 1')
    inst.write('DATA:START 10')
    inst.write('DATA:STOP 800')
    inst.write('DATa:ENCdg RIBinary')  # RIB -128 to +127
```

Because, the failure occurs on the acquisition call (CURVe), I was wondering is there a VISA library call available to solve this problem. Perhaps I need to set the Unicode to UTF-8 or perhaps VISA doesn't deal with Unicodes or perhaps this is not my problem.

Comment: Using the debuggger I receive the following huge string which I have shorten on the exception  (<class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', b'#47991\x16\x16\x16\x17\x17\x16\x16\x16\x16\x14\x16\x15\x16\x17\x15\x17\x16\x16\x17\x15\x16\x16\xx16\x16\x15\x16\x16\x16\x17\ ....... x17\x15\x15\x16\x15\x15\x16\x16\x16\x18\x16\x16\x16\x15\x16\x16\x15\n', 402, 403, 'ordinal not in range(128)'), None)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it was a Unicode problem, but I found the answer in the [pyVisa interface document](http://media.likedoc.net/pdf/pyvisa/latest/pyvisa.pdf). In this document I found the function query_binary_values(), and I replaced the inst.Query('CURVe") with it. This is how I used it.

```
tdsData = inst.query_binary_values('CURVe?', datatype='b', is_big_endian=True)
```

The data that was returned did not have the UnicodeDecodeError, and I was able to plot all the lines with no problem.

Comment: Though this may seem to work I found that it will still truncate values > 128. The real issue here is how pyVisa is encoding/decoding the stream. after changing encoding to 'latin-1' my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Notice in that error it states that it's using 'ascii' encoding. This is not preferred as I'm pretty sure your instrument is outputting a wider range of value than that encoding method can handle:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 401: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So to fix (at least in my case) you can specify a different encoding method.
First reference your instrument in python then set its encoding to 'latin-1'

eg:

```
inst = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x1AB1::0x0588::DS1ET152915193::INSTR')
inst.encoding =  "latin-1"
```

Then to read in the values and convert them to an array of scalars just do something like:

```
data = map(ord, inst.query(":WAVeform:DATA? FFT")) #UTF string to int array conversion
```

data should now contain all "full-ranged" values.